Firebase Custom Domain Showing "Site Not Found"?
I have a Go app which is deployed to Cloud Run. I then used Firebase Hosting to forward all requests to the Cloud Run instance.
When using the Firebase provided domain, everything works correctly. Including the home page.
However, when using a custom domain, I get the "Site Not Found". Interestingly, this only happens on the home page. When heading to a sub route, e.g. "/login", everything seems to work as it should.
Here is my firebase.json file:
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "run": {
          "serviceId": "go-app",
          "region": "europe-west1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

